# How to run this test in NUnit

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

Why in NUnit when i write : 
Assert.AreEqual(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FertigungRead"].ConnectionString , "Data Source=server511;Initial Catalog=FERTIGUNG;Persist Security Info=True");

it does not run the test and raises an error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But ConfigurationManager is static class. So how can i run this test?

Comment: check the my answer to one of your other questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409208/the-problem-with-nunit-and-app-config/5821977#5821977

Answer (score 2):

It *is* running the test - but the test is failing, because `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FertigungRead"]` is returning null.
See [this post about app.config files an NUnit](http://blog.coryfoy.com/2005/08/nunit-app-config-files-its-all-about-the-nunit-file/), as that's where it'll be getting the configuration from.

However, I don't really see a test for a config file value as a valuable unit test... is this part of a more reasonable test?

Comment: yes it is part of more reasonable test, but the error is in the part with ConfigurationManager, so i mentioned only it .

Comment: and i copied the app.config file to the project where i am runing test and have nunit.framework reference included ,but it still doesn't work