# "System.ArgumentNullException : Argument cannot be null" while running NUnit tests through command line

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-console, pnunit

While running NUnit tests through command line (nunit-console.exe assemblyName.dll), ConfigurationManager is not able to read the keys from 'App.config' file hence the program is throwing "System.ArgumentNullException : Argument cannot be null"

I have also copied 'App.config' file to the path from where I am running the Nunit-console.exe

Can some body help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

After spending lot of time, finally I have got the solution in [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409208/the-problem-with-nunit-and-app-config), the issue is because assemblyName.dll.config file is missing.

While running the Nunit tests from the command line, copy the dll.config along wiht the dll. That will solve the issue.